# Jquery AJAX DELETE problem

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, ajax

Any ideas why this does not pass 'id' form value?

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
   var deleteUser = function () {
   var id = this.id.split('lnk_delete_user_')[1];
   console.log(id); //prints frickin "2"
   $.ajax({
     type: "DELETE", url: '<%= Url.Action("DeleteUser") %>', data: "id=" + id,
     success: function (data) {
     window.location.href = '<%= Url.Action("Users") %>'
    }
   });
   };
   $(function ($) { $("a[id^=lnk_delete_user_]").confirm().click(deleteUser); });
</script>
```

Server side does not receive 'id' argument. What might be wrong?

Did check that right before `$.ajax(...)` id equals 2.

Tried rewriting `data: "id="+id,` to `data: {id:id}`, nothing changes.

This is how my action looks like:

```
[HttpDelete]
[Authorize(Roles="admin")]
public ActionResult DeleteUser(string id){
  //does not get even so far
}
```

Comment: Are you sure DELETE is supported on your server?

Comment: Quoting the RFC 2616 Fielding

The DELETE method requests that the origin server delete the resource identified by the Request-URI.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For the moment, you need to POST and not DELETE, like this:

```
$.ajax({
  type: "POST", 
  url: '<%= Url.Action("DeleteUser") %>', 
  data: { id: id },
  success: function (data) {
    window.location.href = '<%= Url.Action("Users") %>'
  }
});
```

jQuery won't properly serialize data parameters for DELETE requests until 1.4.4, [there is already a fix in place for this](http://github.com/jquery/jquery/commit/09022e0b09db71259751e7146bb64727615028af)...so if you can wait for the jQuery 1.4.4 bugfix release, this should be resolved.

Comment: I've tested the OPs code with jquery 1.4.1 which is what is included by default with ASP.NET MVC 2 and it worked perfectly fine.

Comment: @Darin - you're making an assumption that the OP hasn't updated their jQuery version, that's a very risky/often wrong assumption.

Comment: yes using `http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js` doesn't work. Using `http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.1/jquery.min.js` works fine.

Comment: Thanks, @Nick. Going down to v1.4.2 helps. I thought it's JQuery (cause nothing else could change and it did work previously) too. Anyway - wasted way too much time on such a silly problem.

Answer (score 2):

In your script the id javascript variable is not defined. Also I would recommend you using data hash instead of string concatenation as this will ensure proper encoding:

```
$.ajax({
    type: 'DELETE', 
    url: '<%= Url.Action("DeleteUser") %>', 
    data: { id: '123' },
    success: function (data) {
        window.location.href = '<%= Url.Action("Users") %>';
    }
});
```

Where your controller action looks like this:

```
[HttpDelete]
public ActionResult DeleteUser(string id)
{
    throw new NotImplementedException();
}
```

---

UPDATE:

It seems that the problem comes from the fact that you are using jquery from here: http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js

When you include it from google CDN it works fine:

http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.1/jquery.min.js

Comment: Unfortunately - it is defined.

Comment: Where it is defined? I can't see it nowhere in your code snippet. Also look at FireBug to see exactly what's sent to the server. It will facilitate your debugging. I've just tested this code and it worked perfectly fine.

Comment: @Arnis L., try hardcoding the id. Worked for me so the problem is not related to jquery nor ASP.NET MVC. Also you put a comment in your controller action saying it does not get even so far. Where does it get then?

Comment: Thank You for help, but Nick was first. Upvoting for Your time. :)

Answer (score 0):

If id is your a value inside your ASP script then use this:

```
$.ajax({
type: 'DELETE', 
url: '<%= Url.Action("DeleteUser") %>', 
data: { id: <%= id %> },
success: function (data) {
    window.location.href = '<%= Url.Action("Users") %>';
}});
```